# Selenium / Rudy: 'uninitialized constant Contactlist::Runtime (NameError)' error

Tags: ruby, selenium, runtime

What command should I initialize in order to execute `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Script.exe")` in Ruby-selenium environment)

**Code:**

```
class Contactlist
    require "selenium-webdriver"
    require "rubygems"
    require "test/unit"

    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
        driver.navigate.to "https://www.contactually.com/"
        sleep 20
      element = driver.find_element(:css, ".signin>a").click
     sleep 5
      element = driver.find_element(:css, "#user_email")
      element.send_keys "pcroyalpaint@gmail.com"
      element = driver.find_element(:css, "#user_password")
      element.send_keys "Astegic1!"
      element = driver.find_element(:css, ".callout.sign-in-btn").click
      sleep 15
    element = driver.find_element(:xpath, ".//*[@class='ui inverted underlined ApplicationHeader__main-menu___1gsj_ menu']//a[2]").click
    sleep 10
    element = driver.find_element(:xpath,"/.//a[@ href='https://www.contactually.com/contacts/import']").click
    sleep 10
    element =  driver.find_element(:xpath,".//*[@id='file']").click
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Script.exe")
end
```

**Console output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime` is not an object in standard ruby (looks like `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` comes from java?). However if this is implemented elsewhere then you need to `require` or `include`.

If you are just trying to execute a command at the shell level you can use `system('script.exe')`